# Rotational invariance constraints on potential

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, phonons

I have a question about  [Nayak's lecture note](https://archive.org/details/NayakQuantumCondensedMatterPhysicsLectureNotesFreescience2273Year2004/page/n31/mode/1up) , page 20, above equation (2.1)
'Rotational invariance implies that it can only be a function of the symmetric combination,
$$u_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_iu_j+\partial_ju_i)$$'

My question is how to check this symmetric form is rotational invariance. For example, rotation aroun $z$ direction $\theta$, $u_{12}$ is not invariant if
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1\\
u_2
\end{pmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta&\,\,\sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta&\,\,\,\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1\\
u_2
\end{pmatrix},
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{pmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta&\,\,\sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta&\,\,\,\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$